# Laravel Complex Scope Query using chain method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I want to use `user id` of `whereHas` query in the second method. How can I achieve this?

```php
public function scopeloadAvailableAgents($query){
    return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q){
        $q->where("name", "agent");    
    })
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($q) use (/* i want to use user_id of where has query */){
        $q->select('user_id')
            ->from(with(new UserToManager())->getTable())
            ->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

Edit :
`memeber` is a typo.. it will be `agent`. i have on table `agent_to_manager` and i want to fetch only agent roled users that is not present in `agent_to_manager` table.. and i have two queries one that fetch only agent role user and second checks where the fetched users are not present in `agent_to_manager` table.. but i wont able to get the whereHas query's result to run the second query

Comment: Hi, @Amiyo, can you specify better what do you want to achieve? Maybe you can describe the relationships between the models.

Comment: If I understood "the availables agents" is all users which have role.name equals Member but user.id must NOT be equals $user_id. Is there any relationship between user and role?

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes sorry ```member``` is a typo.. there will be two queries.. one will fetch users with role of ```agent``` then second query will check  the ```id```s are not present in ```agent_to_managers``` table..

Comment: OK! But please, describe a little more about, de current model (which has this scope method), its User model? And  UserToManager model, can you describe better? I guess UserToManager belongsTo User and User hasOne UserToManager. If so, the answer can be simple.

Comment: In other words, you basically want to return all `available agents` which means, all users with `agent` role but that is not currently in `agent_to_manager`.  But I need to now the relationship between the model with the scope function and the UserToManager model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function scopeloadAvailableAgents($query, $managerId){

        return $query->whereNotIn('id', function($q) use ($managerId){
            $q->select('user_id')
            ->from(with(new UserToManager())->getTable())
            ->where('manager_id', $managerId);
        })
        ->whereHas('roles', function($q){
            $q->where("name", "agent");
            
        })->get();
        
    }
```